# GUI do Tkinter trava quando executo o código

Tags: python, tkinter

Sou novato em programação e estou fazendo um macro para realizar algumas ações. Esse macro fica em loop:

```
    while True:
    window = win32gui.GetWindowText(win32gui.GetForegroundWindow())
    #print(window)
    now = time.time()
    if "Tibia" in window:
        #Procura IMG
        localAnel = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen(anel, grayscale=True, confidence=0.9)
        localColar = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen(colar, grayscale=True, confidence=0.9)

        #Se localizar a img do Anel
        if localAnel is not None:
            pyautogui.press("NUM1")
            #print("Anel")

        #Se localizar a img do Colar
        if localColar is not None:
            pyautogui.press("NUM3")
            #print("Colar")

        #Usar berserk potion
        if now - last_berserk_potions > usar_berserk_potions * 60:
            last_berserk_potions = now
            pyautogui.press("NUM2")
            #print("Berserk")
```

Preciso criar um botão onde ao clicar ele roda esse código que fica em looping infinito e ao clicar nesse botão novamente ele pare a execução do código.

Estou fazendo a chamada da seguinte maneira:

```
botao = Button(janela, text="Gerar", command=loop, bg="CYAN", fg = "BLACK", font=padrao)
```

Quando clico no botão ele até executa o looping porém a GUI trava.

Answer (score 0):

Tens que definir uma condição no while para terminar o loop.

```
while quit == False:
    ...
```